# How to handle Error code 50000 in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using **wso2esb4.7.0 and wso2dss3.0.0**.
i am getting this error some times not every time
if i tried with multiple user then its successful for 1 or 2 user other returning **50000** error code.
i mentioned this property in every sequence

```
<property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
```

so my user are unable to process there data continue sly why it is getting like this
what is the error behind this? 
error is coming like this

```
[2014-03-06 18:10:01,473]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : endpoint_5c5f8a43ba64941b19b81abcebf92924c90a25e29775053c will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2014-03-06 18:10:01,473]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : endpoint_5c5f8a43ba64941b19b81abcebf92924c90a25e29775053c - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Thu Mar 06 18:10:31 IST 2014
[2014-03-06 18:10:01,475]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:60fea14f-daa6-413e-82b8-8dbb640492c6, Direction: response, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 500000, ERROR_MESSAGE = null
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error code `500000` as you used following property.

`<property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>`

See [ESB Error Handling docs](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Error+Handling).

I think you should investigate why your endpoint is failing.

ESB is suspending your endpoint due to the failure and it will help to make sure ESB is running smoothly.

You can configure suspend on failure related values. [Check ESB doc on Endpoint Error Handling](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Endpoint+Error+Handling).

There is a good [article on error handling](http://wso2.com/library/articles/wso2-enterprise-service-bus-endpoint-error-handling/) as well.

I hope this helps

Comment: thanx for replay. i knew this but if one connection fail why endpoint going into failure mode.It is not accessing another connection for 30sec

Comment: it may cause data lost endpoint will fail because of dss getting wrong data

Comment: You can configure suspend duration. I updated my answer.